# In node.js is the initial program called as a module?

Tags: node.js

When running the command line "node index.js", is index.js treated as a module with "module scope" for variables declared within it or is it global?

For example (in index.js):

```
a = 1;     // is "a" global?
var b = 1; // is "b" global?
```

I know subsequent modules brought in with "require" would have all their variable declarations  declared with "var" stay within the module, but I'm not sure about the initially called js file (usually named index.js) since it's not brought in with "require" (unless node does this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Node treats all script files as modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) with [their own "*module*" scope](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global_objects).

> Node has a simple module loading system. In Node, **files and modules are in one-to-one correspondence.** [...]

The `module` created for the entry script [will be assigned to `require.main`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module):

> When a file is run directly from Node, `require.main` is set to its `module`. That means that you can determine whether a file has been run directly by testing
>
> ```
> require.main === module
> ```

And, you can determined what's a global by using the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) against the [`global` object](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global), which all globals become a property of:

```
a = 1;     // is "a" global?
var b = 1; // is "b" global?

console.log('a' in global); // true
console.log('b' in global); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

The variables declared with the initial file are treated the same as all other files.

If you want to declare a variable as global, attach it to the `GLOBAL` property:

```
GLOBAL.a = 1;  // a should be available in all files
```

(the usual caveats about global variables apply here).

Comment: Is GLOBAL.a the only way to declare a global variable?  Would "a = 1;" be the same as "var a = 1;" in index.js.  Would they both be scoped as part of the "index.js module"?

Comment: Yes, they both are scoped as part of `index.js`